# JavaFX: Deferred coordinate computation

Tags: javafx, fxml

I'm trying to draw a curve between two nodes, which reside in different parent container. The container can be arbitrary deeply nested. I am able to transform the local coordinates into the coordinate space of the common ancestor, however the node bounds are not available, at the time the line is drawn.

In my application I create my nodes in a background thread and add them later to the scene. Therefore the computation of the line coordinates should just be triggered, when the two nodes are fully layouted (they should have a height and width).

I tried to solve the issue with a property change listener, but I cannot find a property which changes enough frequently.

Is there an event I can listen to, which gets triggered if the needed properties are set?

Thank you in advance!

I added a simplified example, which should show the problem. The line is correctly drawn, as soon as you click the "redraw"-Button.

**Application Class:**

```
public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("sample.fxml"));
        primaryStage.setTitle("Showcase");
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 300);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.setResizable(false);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

**sample.fxml**

```
<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.ToolBar?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>

<AnchorPane fx:controller="sample.Controller" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml">

    <ToolBar AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0" prefHeight="50">
        <Button onAction="#redrawEdge" text="Redraw Line"/>
    </ToolBar>

    <AnchorPane fx:id="contentPane" AnchorPane.topAnchor="50"
                AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0"
                AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0"/>

</AnchorPane>
```

**Controller:**

```
public class Controller {

    private final Rectangle node1 = new Rectangle();
    private final Ellipse node2 = new Ellipse();
    private final HBox parent = new HBox();
    private final HBox parent2 = new HBox();
    private final VBox parentParent = new VBox();
    private final Line edge = new Line();

    @FXML
    private AnchorPane contentPane;

    @FXML
    public void initialize() {
        // not updated as expected
        node1.boundsInParentProperty().addListener((o) -> drawLine());
        node2.boundsInParentProperty().addListener((o) -> drawLine());

        node1.setHeight(20);
        node1.setWidth(20);
        node1.setFill(Color.BURLYWOOD);

        node2.setRadiusX(20);
        node2.setRadiusY(20);
        node2.setFill(Color.DEEPSKYBLUE);

        parent.setStyle("-fx-border-color: #DC143C");
        parent.setPadding(new Insets(10));
        parent.getChildren().add(node1);

        parent2.setStyle("-fx-border-color: #5CD3A9");
        parent2.setPadding(new Insets(10));
        parent2.getChildren().add(node2);

        parentParent.setStyle("-fx-border-color: #0336FF");
        parentParent.setLayoutX(200);
        parentParent.setLayoutY(50);
        parentParent.setPadding(new Insets(10));
        parentParent.getChildren().add(parent);

        contentPane.setStyle("-fx-border-color: #4B0082;");
        contentPane.setPadding(new Insets(10));
        contentPane.getChildren().addAll(parentParent, parent2, edge);
    }

    @FXML
    public void redrawEdge(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
        drawLine();
    }

    private void drawLine() {
        Bounds n1InCommonAncestor = getRelativeBounds(node1, contentPane);
        Bounds n2InCommonAncestor = getRelativeBounds(node2, contentPane);
        Point2D n1Center = getCenter(n1InCommonAncestor);
        Point2D n2Center = getCenter(n2InCommonAncestor);

        Point2D startIntersection = findIntersectionPoint(n1InCommonAncestor,
                n1Center, n2Center);
        Point2D endIntersection = findIntersectionPoint(n2InCommonAncestor,
                n2Center, n1Center);

        edge.setStartX(startIntersection.getX());
        edge.setStartY(startIntersection.getY());
        edge.setEndX(endIntersection.getX());
        edge.setEndY(endIntersection.getY());
    }

    private Bounds getRelativeBounds(Node node, Node relativeTo) {
        Bounds nodeBoundsInScene = node.localToScene(node.getBoundsInLocal());
        return relativeTo.sceneToLocal(nodeBoundsInScene);
    }

    private Point2D getCenter(Bounds bounds) {
        return new Point2D(bounds.getMinX() + bounds.getWidth() / 2,
                bounds.getMinY() + bounds.getHeight() / 2);
    }

    private Point2D findIntersectionPoint(Bounds nodeBounds,
                                          Point2D inside, Point2D outside) {

        Point2D middle = outside.midpoint(inside);

        double deltaX = outside.getX() - inside.getX();
        double deltaY = outside.getY() - inside.getY();

        if (Math.hypot(deltaX, deltaY) < 1.) {
            return middle;
        } else {
            if (nodeBounds.contains(middle)) {
                return findIntersectionPoint(nodeBounds, middle, outside);
            } else {
                return findIntersectionPoint(nodeBounds, inside, middle);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Creating the following should work, though you may need to consider consequences on performance in some circumstances:

```
Node node = ... ;

ObjectBinding<Bounds> boundsInScene = new ObjectBinding<Bounds>() {

    {
        bind(node.boundsInLocalProperty(), node.localToSceneTransformProperty());
    }

    @Override
    protected Bounds computeValue() {
        return node.localToScene(node.getBoundsInLocal());
    }
};
```

You could also do something similar for the relative bounds:

```
Node node1 = ... ;
Node node2 = ... ;

ObjectBinding<Bounds> relativeBounds = new ObjectBinding<Bounds>() {

    {
        bind(
            node1.boundsInLocalProperty(),
            node1.localToSceneTransformProperty(),
            node2.boundsInLocalProperty(),
            node2.localToSceneTransformProperty()
        );
    }

    @Override
    protected Bounds computeValue() {
        return node2.sceneToLocal(node1.localToScene(node1.getBoundsInLocal()));
    }
};
```

Adding listeners to these, and redrawing when they change, should give you the control you need over when to redraw.

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick reply! I tried to add a listener for the relativeBounds object binding, but this is only triggered once in a too early stage.

Comment: Hmm. Somehow, it seems some of the intermediate bindings are getting garbage collected somewhere. I'll see if I can figure it out an will update...